# Discussions of and reference for when the axiom of "moving a quantifier past a formula" holds as an equivalence

Tags: logic, reference-request, first-order-logic, proof-theory

One of the usual axioms of first-order predicate calculus is, roughly:

if $P_0$ and $P_1$ are formulas, and if in $P_0$ the variable does not occur freely, then the following is valid:

$ \bigl(\forall x:T\quad (P_0\rightarrow P_1)\bigr)\rightarrow (P_0\rightarrow \forall x:T\quad P_1)$

Sometimes, this is an equivalence, i.e., in some situations, also

$ \bigl(\forall x:T\quad (P_0\rightarrow P_1)\bigr)\leftarrow (P_0\rightarrow \forall x:T\quad P_1)$

is valid.

**Question**: can you recommend references where this is discussed, preferably in general (precise general conditions of when the converse implication holds, examples perhaps, and perhaps a discussion why it is so usual to only give the first-cited implication)?

Remarks.

- I am more interested in high-level discussions of this issue, or perhaps stories of the kind "Yeah, this is called such and such, and I needed this too for this and that.", less in elementary explanations of first-order logic.
- The type-theoretic notation $x:T$ was not used for a particular reason; rather, I am currently working with this notation, and would therefore prefer to read somewhat "type-theoretically-informed" discussions
- Motivation for this question is that I had to convince myself that a certain assignation of morphisms to morphisms in a category is really a functor. I was suspecting that something was wrong with it, and found myself constructing a formal proof that composition is preserved. In it, I need the equivalence

$ \bigl(\forall x:T\quad (P_0\rightarrow P_1)\bigr)\leftrightarrow (P_0\rightarrow \forall x:T\quad P_1)$

which happens to hold at that point. When it comes to presenting this to readers or an audience, the issue arises of what to appeal to. The off-the-shelf axioms known to me only state the implication.

Comment: Doesn't the equivalence *always* hold when $x$ does not occur freely in $P_0$? When presenting this, can't you just say "since this is equivalence is a first-order tautology..." and move on?

Comment: Intuitively, I think this is an equivalence. But then again, if one is to present this in a very formal treatment, one has to give a reference. And the references I know all state only the implication (probably because they do not have $\leftrightarrow$ as part of their primitive logical symbols). So this is more or less a vague reference request, or an "exposition problem". I recognize that there is no precise answer as long as one does not precisely fix a proof-system. (Thanks for correcting the typos in the question btw.)

Comment: Will leave this open, despite the answers, since strictly speaking the question is not answered yet; this is probably because it simply does not have an answer. This is simply not a logical principle usual enough to have  become common coin and entered the vernacular, such as _modus ponens_, or _de Morgan laws_, or _contrapositive_, which one can reference by names. One solution is of course to either introduce a formal proof system, or to recalibrate the degree of formality of the exposition one is trying to give.

Comment: The inference in the question is a generalization of "$A \vdash B_1$ and $A \vdash B_2$, if and only if $A \vdash B_1 \land B_2$".  It even holds in an empty universe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a logical *equivalence*, i.e. the equivalence *always* holds, not just sometimes.

Here is a not quite formal discussion as to whym (sorry, I have no reference ... I just do this by pure logic)

You can see any universal as a kind of conjunction. That is, you can think of $\forall x: T \quad P(x)$ as saying: 'object $a$ has property $P$, *and* object $b$ has property $P$, *and* ...'. In other words (and here is where things are not quite formal!):

$$\forall x: T \ P(x) \approx P(a) \land P(b) \land ....$$

As such, we can explain the logical equivalence $\forall x (P_0 \lor P(x)) \Leftrightarrow  (P_0 \lor \forall x P(x))$ where $P_0$ does not contain $x$ as a free variable:

$$\forall x (P_0 \lor P(x)) \approx$$

$$(P_0 \lor P(a) \land (P_0 \lor P(b) \land ... \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Reverse Distribution)}$$

$$P_0 \lor (P(a) \land P(b) \land ...) \approx $$

$$P_0 \lor \forall x P(x)$$

(using formal semantics, you can prove this equivalence mathematically, but you said you wanted it not too technical/detailed)

Anyway, with that equivalence in place, we can prove your equivalence as well:

$$\forall x (P_0 \to P(x)) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Implication)}$$

$$\forall x (\neg P_0 \lor P(x)) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (given what we just showed)}$$

$$\neg P_0 \lor  \forall x \ P(x) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Implication)}$$

$$P_0 \to  \forall x \ P(x)$$

Comment: This is an interesting semi-formal explanation, thanks. This is more in the direction of an explanation of _why_ it is true, not _how_ to get over this quickly in an exposition, which is why I will not accept the answer formally, hoping for some unexpected helpful references. I recognize that there probably is no convenient standard reference or technical term for this, and that the question is vague. Thanks again, though.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with your notation. In more standard predicate notation, I'm guessing you meant $$\forall x:[T(x) \implies [P_0 \implies P_1(x)]]\space \equiv \space [P_0\implies \forall x:[T(x) \implies P_1(x)]]$$

We can derive this axiom (actually a theorem) as follows using other simpler and easier-to-use axioms.

1. $\forall x:[T(x) \implies [P_0 \implies P_1(x)]]\space$ (Premise)
2. $P_0\space$ (Premise)
3. $T(a)\space$ (Premise)
4. $T(a) \implies [P_0 \implies P_1(a)]\space$ (Universal Specification, 1)
5. $P_0 \implies P_1(a)\space$ (Detachment, 4, 3)
6. $P_1(a)\space$ (Detachment, 5, 2)
7. $\forall x :[T(x) \implies P_1(x)]\space$ (Conclusion, 3)
8. $P_0 \implies \forall x: [T(x) \implies P_1(x)]\space$ (Conclusion, 2)
9. $\forall x:[T(x) \implies [P_0 \implies P_1(x)]]\implies [P_0\implies \forall x:[T(x) \implies P_1(x)]]\space$ (Conclusion, 1)

Similarly, prove the converse.